# Change the width of a card in Gallery view of a List

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, json-formatting, view-formatting

I've been been thinking of migrating our existing FAQ from a wiki to a List in SharePoint Online. Changing the view to a Gallery looks promising:

[image]

But is there a simple way to make the cards wider?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do that using [JSON view formatting](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/view-formatting).

Follow below steps:

1. Go to your SharePoint list
2. Click on **switch view options** dropdown at the top & select **Format current view**.

   [image]
3. Make sure **Format view** & **Gallery** is selected like below:

   [image]
4. Click on **Edit card** & then select **Advanced mode**
5. In the JSON text box below, change the `width` property as per your requirements like:

   ```
     "width": 500,
   ```

   [image]
6. Click **Save**

Width of the card will be increased like below:

[image]

Comment: Thanks - exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: There does appear to be a limit on the width though. Any idea how to get past that limit?

Comment: I think I've figured it out - the max width is a function of the height (x2), so I have to make the height larger.

Comment: Great, glad it worked for you.