# Set width of Cards to Full Screen using JSON view formatting without changing height

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, json-formatting, view-formatting

**How can I set the width of the Cards (or Tiles) in SPO Modern views to full screen without having to increase the height?**

I'd like to set the width to 1500px but the width is somehow tied to the height property.  I can get it to go full screen but only if the height is at least 500.  I want the height to be 200.

I've worked with the Card/Tile layout in SPO modern views quite a bit and I have a good handle on it, but this problem is perplexing.

**How can we override the linkage between the height/width properties of the Card?**

I've tried all of the following:

- Removing the class on the container,
  `"class": "sp-card-container"`
- Adding the height/width properties to the first div element.
- Setting min-height and max-height values
- Setting fillHorizontally to false or removing it entirely.

None of those made a difference.

This post states the max width is 2x the height. I don't know if that ratio is exact but there's certainly some restriction based on height:

[Change the width of a card in Gallery view of a List](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/293460/change-the-width-of-a-card-in-gallery-view-of-a-list)

My code is just the default Gallery Card with a tweak to the height and width values:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/tile-formatting.schema.json",
  "height": 200,
  "width": 1500,
  "hideSelection": false,
  "fillHorizontally": true,
  "formatter": {
    "elmType": "div",
    "attributes": {
      "class": "sp-card-container"
    },
    "children": [
      {
        "elmType": "div",
        "attributes": {
          "class": "sp-card-defaultClickButton"
        },
        "customRowAction": {
          "action": "defaultClick"
        }
      },
      {
        "elmType": "div",
        "attributes": {
          "class": "ms-bgColor-white sp-css-borderColor-neutralLight sp-card-borderHighlight sp-card-subContainer"
        },
        "children": [
          {
            "elmType": "div",
            "attributes": {
              "class": "sp-card-displayColumnContainer"
            },
            "children": [
              {
                "elmType": "p",
                "attributes": {
                  "title": "[$Title]",
                  "class": "ms-fontColor-neutralPrimary sp-card-content sp-card-highlightedContent",
                  "role": "heading",
                  "aria-level": "3"
                },
                "txtContent": "=if ([$Title] == '', '–', [$Title])"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "elmType": "div",
            "attributes": {
              "class": "sp-card-displayColumnContainer"
            },
            "children": [
              {
                "elmType": "p",
                "attributes": {
                  "title": "[$Icon1]",
                  "class": "ms-fontColor-neutralPrimary sp-card-content "
                },
                "txtContent": "=if ([$Icon1] == '', '–', [$Icon1])"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "elmType": "div",
            "attributes": {
              "class": "sp-card-displayColumnContainer"
            },
            "children": [
              {
                "elmType": "a",
                "attributes": {
                  "title": "[$Link1]",
                  "class": "ms-fontColor-neutralPrimary sp-card-content sp-card-urlContent  sp-card-keyboard-focusable",
                  "href": "[$Link1]",
                  "target": "=if ([$Link1] == '', '', '_blank')"
                },
                "style": {
                  "pointer-events": "=if ([$Link1] == '', 'none', 'auto')",
                  "text-decoration": "=if ([$Link1] == '', 'none', 'auto')"
                },
                "txtContent": "=if ([$Link1.desc] == '', '–', [$Link1.desc])"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "elmType": "div",
            "attributes": {
              "class": "sp-card-displayColumnContainer"
            },
            "children": [
              {
                "elmType": "p",
                "attributes": {
                  "title": "[$Icon2]",
                  "class": "ms-fontColor-neutralPrimary sp-card-content "
                },
                "txtContent": "=if ([$Icon2] == '', '–', [$Icon2])"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "elmType": "div",
            "attributes": {
              "class": "sp-card-lastTextColumnContainer"
            },
            "children": [
              {
                "elmType": "a",
                "attributes": {
                  "title": "[$Link2]",
                  "class": "ms-fontColor-neutralPrimary sp-card-content sp-card-urlContent  sp-card-keyboard-focusable",
                  "href": "[$Link2]",
                  "target": "=if ([$Link2] == '', '', '_blank')"
                },
                "style": {
                  "pointer-events": "=if ([$Link2] == '', 'none', 'auto')",
                  "text-decoration": "=if ([$Link2] == '', 'none', 'auto')"
                },
                "txtContent": "=if ([$Link2.desc] == '', '–', [$Link2.desc])"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Thank you